# Brocade SX800 Management Problem

Tags: switch, router, brocade

In my company we have a brocade sx800 backbone SW, it is not used for 4 years. Now we need it for new warehouse project.But we don't know what was the ip addresses and no info about this device. When i try to connect with serial cable, nothing happen. How can i reset this device or how can i reach the management interface.

[[image: Connetion with serial cable and console converter][1]]

[image: Putty connection screen]

Comment: Possible DTE/DCE mismatch, or completely wrong pinout in the RJ45 adapter. (I have a small draw full of them because too many nuts think RS232 isn't a standard.) EDIT: try a null-modem adapter.

Comment: Thanks for your return, i found a null-modem adapter and it worked. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ricky pointed out, i found a null-modem adapter and it worked. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the correct serial cable. Additionally, hit [Enter] a couple of times.

[image]

https://www.manualslib.com/manual/808969/Brocade-Communications-Systems-Fastiron-Cx.html?page=37

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i have tried with different DB9-DTE serial connector and pressed enter like hundreds of times. It still on same screen .

Comment: *tried different serial connectors* won't help if none of them has the required pinout - have you verified that?

Comment: Yes,  i verified pinout https://imgur.com/KV4ybrz